# DELETE request running twice

Tags: django, http, http-delete

I'm running a site with Django and I only have access to the backend.

When I delete an item through the web interface (an alert) the `DELETE` request is run twice:

```
/alerts/[alert_id]
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 301 Moved Permanently
```

then

```
/alerts/[alert_id]/
Request Method: DELETE
Status Code: 204 No Content
```

Any thoughts as to where the issue could be or why it does this? Apparently the frontend **only** calls the request that ends with a slash (the second one)

Comment: can you add code portion by which you run delete?

Comment: Your request is not run twice. It's redirected to the correct URL. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) for more info.

Comment: It looks like you view sends to a client browser 301 (redirect) with the same URL. The Browser resend query to the same URL, and you got it second time. But your view process it differently (because the resource is already deleted).

Comment: I checked the docs and yeah that does seem to be the problem... thanks everyone ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#append-slash) explained the problem, I just didn't know what I was looking for

> if the request URL does not match any of the patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended.

Answer (score 1):

The `HTTP 204 No Content` success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded, but that the client doesn't need to go away from its current page. A `204` response is cacheable by default. An ETag header is included in such a response.

The common use case is to return `204` as a result of a PUT request, updating a resource, without changing the current content of the page displayed to the user.

[Source file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204)